# electron-forge package unable to package file typings.d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, electron-forge

electron-forge package

Fail

with angular project

Looks that it is unable to package file typings.d.ts

here is the error

```
PS  electron-forge package
√ Checking your system
√ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
/ Compiling ApplicationFailed to compile file: ***\electon-win32-x64\resources\app\src\typings.d.ts
Debug Failure. False expression: Output generation failed
```

any ideas